# Reticulate can't access R variables in Python when knitting unless running in RStudio

Tags: r, r-markdown, reticulate

I have an RMarkdown document with the following content:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(reticulate)
```

```{r}
#These lines don't seem to make a difference, but I have seen them suggested elsewhere
reticulate::use_python('/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6_2/bin/python3.8')
knitr::knit_engines$set(python = reticulate::eng_python)
```


```{r}
py <- reticulate::py
```


```{python}
import sys
sys.version

a = 1
```


```{r python from r}
print(py$a)
b <- 2
```

```{python r from python}
print(r.b)
```
````

If I run this in RStudio, either interactively or by knitting the whole document, everything works and the last chunk prints "2". However, when running from the R console through `render` (or my production script that performs regular model trainings) it fails on the last chunk with the following error:

> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :
> RuntimeError: Evaluation error: object 'b' not found.
>
> Detailed traceback:    File "", line 1, in    File
> "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/reticulate/python/rpytools/call.py",
> line 21, in python_function
> raise RuntimeError(res[kErrorKey])

Accessing Python variables from R seems to work properly, but I cannot access R variables in Python.

I am using Reticulate 1.18, Knitr 1.30, and rMarkdown 2.6. Calling `py_config()` from both RStudio and the R console returns the same result:

> >py_config()
>
> python:         /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6_2/bin/python3.8 libpython:
> /usr/local/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-darwin/libpython3.8.dylib
> pythonhome:
> /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8:/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.6_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8
> version:        3.8.6 (default, Nov 20 2020, 18:29:40)  [Clang 12.0.0
> (clang-1200.0.32.27)] numpy:
> /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy numpy_version:  1.18.5
>
> NOTE: Python version was forced by RETICULATE_PYTHON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is broken in the current version of Reticulate. I downgraded to 1.16 and that fixed it, 1.17 and later are broken. I've submitted a ticket to the devs: https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/914

Edit: This is now fixed in the latest dev version, which can be installed with remotes::install_github("rstudio/reticulate")

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me because I had the stupid idea to name an object `r` in a RMarkdown script

````py
```{python}
import requests
r = requests.get('http://api.worldbank.org/v2/countries?incomeLevel=LMC')
r.content
```
````

will work in a python interpreter but might return an error in a RMarkdown document (because `reticulate` looks for the object `content` in python environment)

Best workaround: never naming an object `r` when using `reticulate`